Spring Boot: all tests are failing with IllegalStateException, NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundExcpetion
I am tasked with the sacred duty of migrating to Spring Boot 3. I'm working on a particular service, and as I run the tests, all of them fail immediately. Pretty obvious that one thing is the culprit. And I need your help in finding that nasty little muppet
Below are the error logs I get when running the tests:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on QueueController

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [RestTemplateConfig] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader]

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient

What I tried already:
I tried investigating org.apache.httpclient, and saw the version is indeed 5, which is compliant with Spring Boot 3. A parent service inherits it
I'm out of ideas lads, any help is appreciated. I can share the pom.xml if required.

Share your pom.xml

This question is similar to: I am migrating spring boot version 2.7.3 to spring-boot 3.0.0 so existing code is breaking related to HttpClients. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@AnishB. I checked it out. Unsure if it's relevant because my version for HttpClient is 5, which is compliant with Spring Boot 3
